# VB Script + Opening excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I don't know VBScript. In my SAP BSP page there is piece of VBScript code as below.

```
<script language="VBScript">
    'On Error Resume Next
    xlNone = -4142
    xlContinuous = 1
    xlDash = -4115
    xlDashDot = 4
    xlDashDotDot = 5
    xlDot = -4118
    xlDouble = -4119
    xlSlantDashDot = 13

    'These define the weight of the border
    xlHairLine = 1
    xlMedium = -4138
    xlThick = 4
    xlThin = 2

    'Thise is handy to make borders have the default color index
    xlAutomatic = 5

    'These define the placement of border pieces
    xlDiagonalDown = 5
    xlDiagonalUp = 6
    xlEdgeLeft = 7
    xlEdgeTop = 8
    xlEdgeBottom = 9
    xlEdgeRight = 10
    xlInsideVertical = 11
    xlInsideHorizontal = 12
    set Excel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Excel.Visible = true
    set wb   =  Excel.Workbooks.Open("<%= gv_excel_url%>")
    Set s    = wb.Worksheets("DRM Data")
    s.DisplayGridlines = not s.DisplayGridlines
</script>
```

In debugging I can not see all details.
If you see below statement.

```
set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("<%= gv_excel_url%>")
```

Here `gv_excel_url` will have some system path for which I don't have authorization to open directly.

In debugging once it executes this statement it does not execute the statements below.

```
Set s = wb.Worksheets("DRM Data")
s.DisplayGridlines = not s.DisplayGridlines
```

Control goes further down.

Finally my Excel does not open with required data.
Would you please tell me whether statement `set wb =  Excel.Workbooks.Open("<%= gv_excel_url%>")` checks authorization or not?

Can I debug this piece of code? How I can see the value of `wb` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `<%= %>` on that statement. You're already within a `<script>` tag. Change the line to:

```
set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(gv_excel_url)
```

I'm curious, though... if you don't have the authorization to open this file, how is the VBScript going to do it for you?